# `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number` when converting a tuple containing datetime objects to a numpy structured array

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, numpy

I am trying to plot a graph in Python using data from MySQL but I am getting the following error:

```
File "mygraph.py", line 45, in <module>
    Raw = numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1, dtype=[('', numpy.float)]*3)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

The dates are saved in the database using `datetime` format. Below is a part of my code:

```
cursor = DBconn.cursor()
sql = "select mydate,temp,hum from temptable where unix_timestamp(mydate) >= (unix_timestamp(now())-(60*60*24))"
cursor.execute(sql)
Raw = numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1, dtype=[('', numpy.float)]*3)
Raw = Raw.view(numpy.float).reshape(-1, 3)
(samples,ports)=Raw.shape
print 'Samples: {}, DataPoints: {}'.format(samples,ports),
plotme=numpy.zeros((samples,ports-1)) # make an array the same shape minus the epoch numbers
```

The problem might be in the way the date is formatted e.g. I saved in `datetime` but I am calling using epoch? Can anyone guide me on how to fix this?

Update: `cursor.fetchall()` prints the following:

```
((datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 24, 21, 2, 1), Decimal('21.4'), Decimal('60.9')))
```

Comment: What exactly does `cursor.fetchall()` return? If the values are datetime then why are you casting them to floats?

Comment: I saved the date in datetime but the code I am using, assumes that the values are in epoch format. I can't find a way to convert it to epoch.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show an example of what `cursor.fetchall()` returns? It's not clear to me exactly what input format you're dealing with.

Comment: @ali_m I have added the result of cursor.fetchall().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dtype you specified in your call to `np.fromiter` does not match the corresponding types for the list of tuples returned by `cursor.fetchall()`. The first item in each tuple is a `datetime.datetime`, but your dtype consists of all floats. Since there is no safe way to cast a `datetime.datetime` to a float, you get a `TypeError`.

Try making the first field [`numpy.datetime64`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) rather than float:

```
numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1,
               dtype=zip(('',) * 3, ('M8[us]', '<f8', '<f8'))))
```